# Find the unique values stored within a selected attribute of an active layer in PYQGIS

Tags: python, pyqgis

I've created a program in the python console in QGIS that loops through the active layer in catalog and appends each attribute within the active layer that is a string datatype to a list[]. I then used that list to create an input dialog box in the console. After a selection is made in the dialog box, the program is supposed to filter out the unique values of the attribute selected. I ran into a road block here because the values returned from the attribute selected in the dialog box are a string and I don't know how to return only unique values. I only know how to return all the values.

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

lyr = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
lyr = iface.activeLayer()

print(lyr.name())
print(lyr.featureCount())

#
# ... access fields of a layer 
#

attributeName = []
allFields = lyr.fields()
for field in allFields:
    if field.typeName() == "String":
        attributeName.append(field.name())
    print("Name: %s" % field.name())
    print("Type name (Data type): %s" % field.typeName())
print(attributeName)

#
# ... present the user with an option list 
#

lbl4dialog = "Enter number for selection:\n"
for i in range(len(attributeName)):
    lbl4dialog = lbl4dialog + ("%d. %s\n" %(i+1,attributeName[i])) 

qid = QInputDialog()

title = "Enter Your Name"
label = lbl4dialog 
mode = QLineEdit.Normal
default = "1"

AttributeSelected, ok = QInputDialog.getText(qid, title, label, mode, default)

print(AttributeSelected)

print(attributeName[int(AttributeSelected) - 1])

##access values in a column for each feature stored in layer 

currField = (attributeName[int(AttributeSelected) - 1])
currFeatCount = lyr.featureCount()

for i in range(currFeatCount): 
    currFeature = lyr.getFeature(i)
    print(currFeature[currField])
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple create a list, fill in all values and make the list unique?

```
vl = []
for f in lyr.getFeatures():
    vl.append(f[currField])

vl = list(dict.fromkeys(vl))
```

Tip: QgsVectorLayerUtils.getValues(...) => https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayerUtils.html